# Override/update environment variable of a docker container

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I have a docker container on a service that I can't start or modify myself. I need to add a few more environment variables to it.
I can access to it, and do some docker exec inside it, once it is running. But exec is ephemeral.

I was wondering, is there a way to override/add/update a docker container variables while it is running? Or maybe stop, update and run the container by its name again?

Thank you,
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this without deleting and recreating the container.

At a Unix level, a process's environment variables are fixed once the process starts.  The process can change its own environment but nothing else can; if a process launches child processes, the parent can specify the childrens' initial environments, but once they start it can't modify them further.

At a Docker level, the "parent" process for this becomes the Docker daemon.  So you can specify the main container process's initial environment (through *e.g.* `docker run -e` flags), but once the container's started, you can't change that environment any further.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for you clear and complete answer! I understand it better now.